# Cycle in dependencies between targets - Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode13

I am getting the following error only on Xcode 13.4.1 when I am trying to build the project.

`Cycle in dependencies between targets '#aTargetName' and '#anotherTargetName'; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.`

It gets solved if I **"clean build folder"** every time I need to run the project.

This is how the build phases are in the project:

[image]

*****Update on 1/07/22:**
The following line fix this:
Open Terminal and run:
`defaults write com.apple.dt.XCBuild EnableSwiftBuildSystemIntegration 1`

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually have a circular dependency?

Comment: Yes, I am. I do not get any building error on previous Xcode verisons.

Comment: [This thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702349) might help

Comment: The following fix this: Open Terminal and run `defaults write com.apple.dt.XCBuild EnableSwiftBuildSystemIntegration 1`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. All the other SO questions refer to changing the order of the 'Headers' in the build phases or updating the build system to legacy.

I don't have a Headers phase so I just played around with what phases I did have. This is a daunting suggestion for anyone with more a few phases because permutations grow exponentially.

For myself here is the before (not working) and after (working) configuration.

**Not Working**
[image: Not Working Build Phases]
**Working**
[image: Working Build Phases]

I have no idea why one is working and the other isn't just that this change resolved my issue. I also commented out some localizing and linting scripts that aren't essential to run on release just dev/test builds. I also only got the error when arching the project - not when buildling.